# Can a Lambda function be automatically called when a AWS MySQL RDS table has a data inserted or updated?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am working on a requirement where I have to trigger a lambda function whenever there is any insert or update in my AWS MySQL RDS table.
I know it is possible with DynamoDB but I am trying to find out a way to implement this using MySQL RDS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box solution for that. But a way to achieve that is described in AWS blog:

- [Streaming Changes in a Database with Amazon Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/streaming-changes-in-a-database-with-amazon-kinesis/)

So you could possibly implement such a solution for yourself.

Comment: Maybe as an addition: If you choose to use the MySQL-compatible version of Aurora instead of RDS, you can have Lambda-based triggers: [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html)

Answer (score 0):

use CDC debezium. But there are limitation in RDS.